# Ansible: Command works in terminal but not Ansible

Tags: ansible

```
awk 'FNR==1{print ""}{print}' *.txt > virtual.txt | mv virtual.txt virtual.csv
```

Works on terminal but not when I add it to an ansible script.

I tried originally:

```
shell: cd Users/Virtual |awk 'FNR==1{print ""}{print}' *.txt > virtual.txt | mv virtual.txt virtual.csv
```

It didn't work. Tried the text below and it cannot find the file

```
- command: chdir=/Users/Virtual awk 'FNR==1{print ""}{print}' *.txt > virtual.txt    
    - shell: "awk 'FNR==1{print ''}{print}' *.txt > virtual.txt" 
    - shell: "mv virtual.txt /Users/virtual.csv"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sure why you try to pipe the output from one command to another...
You usually want to use `&&` or `||` to execute several commands one after another.
Try this one:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - shell: "awk 'FNR==1{print \"\"}{print}' *.txt > virtual.txt && mv virtual.txt virtual.csv"
      args:
        chdir: /Users/Virtual
```